# Eclipse cannot find javaw.exe

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

When i start eclipse i get this problem:

[image]

The location of javaw.exe in my computer is C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin. I have tried change the path environment variable then i get different error like:

[image]

Comment: So, where is jvm.dll?

Comment: You are most likely trying to use a 32-bit Eclipse with a 64-bit JRE.

Comment: Or the other way round.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also got this Eclipse open refusal bug now after the JRE was updated to jre1.8.0_111.

For some reason it was trying to find a jre1.8.0_101/bin/javaw.exe instead of the jre1.8.0_111/bin/javaw.exe file . . .

Solution was to go to the eclipse Configuration Settings file and then change

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin/javaw.exe
```

to

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin/javaw.exe
```

Why was the virtual machine pointed at a file called

```
jre1.8.0_101/bin/javaw.exe
```

in the first place ?

Search me but I don't know !

Comment: Where is that 'Configuration Settings' file? What's the filename? On Windows, I tired to modify Eclipse.ini but there was no -vm and when I added the problem was not solved.

Comment: Eclipse.ini is the correct file. The 2 lines in this should be like this:                       -vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/javaw.exe (or wherever your jre is)     What is your Eclipse version ? Neon.1 or Neon.2 ? BTW, the jre is now 1.8.0_121 after a recent Java JRE update.

Comment: Did somebody modify the eclipse configuration settings file previously?  This is normally not set.

Comment: Not sure if it always needs manual setting or if it seeks the most recent version of the JRE when a new Eclipse version is installed.

Answer (score 5):

Following the comment of @nitind, I've checked the bit depth of my Eclipse and of the installed Java. It turned out that, apparently, during the recent update the Java installer has deleted the old 64 bit installation (so program files/java/jre7/ became empty. After downloading the 64 bit version manually (from http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp), I'm now able to run Eclipse again.

Answer (score 3):

Try starting your eclipse.ini (in the same directory with eclipse.exe) with the two lines:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/javaw.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

`JAVA_HOME` should be added like ***c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0***, and `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` should be added to the PATH variable. Then it works without issues.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME should be left as it was before, eg `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0`, and `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` should be added to the PATH variable, so all required files are available in the environment.

That should be all you need to run Eclipse. If you'd like to specify a diferent vm, take a look at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

If you updated your JRE as did I, eclipse will send the same error report. To correct this issue I went into the eclipse path (i.e) path\eclipse\jee-mars\eclipse and updated the "eclipse configuration-setting" file.

Open the file in some form of editior, I used notepad++. Update the version of JRE on this line..."C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin" save the file and start eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

i was faced this issue because my JAVA_HOME is not there in the system environment, path variable don't have the java related info.

so go to the elipse folder and edited the "eclipse.ini" file with below lines after "openFile" line

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\javaw.exe

it solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Since it has told you that it was looking in D:\Eclipse\jre\bin\ for
>   javaw.exe go to C: <- your computer look in program files or else
>   where for java.  java will contain a file that has a jre\bin\ and you
>   will find javaw.exe copy the contents of bin to D:\Eclipse\jre\bin\
>   and you are set.
>
> alternatively copy the the jre file inside the java folder and replace
>   the jre file in the Eclipse folder and you are set.
>
> Now the above (first) solution works but is bad practice.
>
> Good practice is to have your jre folder set in your path variables.

Answer (score 0):

so for any complete noobs like me move the java dev kit (JDK) to the eclipse folder and rename it jre

Answer (score -1):

Please map correctly java path in environment varibales like below.
it will be resolved.
Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin;

For sure it will be resolved

Comment: Which assumes the OP is using V1.6, which he or she clearly isn't. Also, it would be nice if you showed _how_ to set the environment variables.