# Can't open eclipse with Windows 7 (doesn't see jdk jde)

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, jde

I'm trying to open eclipse for the first time, but otherwise I have this same problem as [[Eclipse cannot find javaw.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453509/eclipse-cannot-find-javaw-exe#new-answer]).

The bit depth isn't resolving the issue.  I have JDE & JDK 8 update 45 installed, and I've downloaded latest 64-bit version of Eclipse.

The information given on command line is a little over my head. I have very little experience with using the command line.  I tried running the `-vm` switch and the path, but it doesn't recognize -vm as a command.

Can anyone give more explicit info on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using `Eclipse` 64 bit and `JRE` and `JDK` on 32 bit? this will not work, as `Eclipse` searches for the `JRE/JDK` installed matching its own bits.

so either all is 32 bit or all is 64 bit

Comment: did you reboot? and is JAVA_HOME and the PATH installation correct? (open cmd and get java version)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the environment variables JAVA_HOME and the PATH to your installation of JDK.

See http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: trying this now but the windows link seems to be broken. windows cannot find systempropertiesadvanced.exe

Answer (score 0):

> but it doesn't recognize -vm as a command

it works fine if placed in the eclipse.ini

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin
[...default configuration below]
```

adjust path as needed of course